# change global-variable inside jquery function

Tags: jquery, global-variables

How do you change a global-variable inside a jquery function. If I use this code below it will display "0" and not "15".

```
<script type>
theValue=0;
      $(document).ready(function(){
    theValue=15;
     });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(theValue)
</script>
```

Comment: that's because `$(document).ready(...)` fires after the document is ready so theValue hasn't changed yet when `document.write(theValue)` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because when you write, the (document).ready hasn't fired yet.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z7YLg/),
notice it writes 0 but when you click the button its 15.